# Continue to get an error that something is not a function but cannot find why

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have been trying to create something for a class where there are 145 boxes and every fifth one is white. By clicking on a box the color should change to the opposite color and hovering over them should change the opacity. I have been able to create the 145 boxes in the right way, but I cannot figure out how to have the click change them. I cannot change the html I was given in any way so I have to use functions and event listeners to change them. I tried to create a function that would change any black box clicked on to a white box but it says it is not a function(error on the last line). I'm probably just making a simple mistake, can anyone help me and/or push me in the right direction.

Html (given):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>A test</title>

    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#337799; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <div id="wrapper" style="width:960px; overflow:hidden; margin:auto; background-color:black;">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="assignment10.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
var blackBg = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for (var i=1; i<145; i++){

var repeatSq = document.createElement('div');

repeatSq.style.float = "left";
repeatSq.style.height = "50px";
repeatSq.style.width = "50px";
repeatSq.style.backgroundColor = "black";
repeatSq.style.opacity = ".5";
repeatSq.style.border = "solid black 5px";
repeatSq.className = "black";

if(i%5 === 0){
    repeatSq.style.backgroundColor= "white";
    repeatSq.style.border= "solid white 5px";
    repeatSq.className = "white";
}

blackBg.appendChild(repeatSq);

}

var blackBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('black');

var boxChange = function(evt){

evt.target.style.backgroundColor="white";
evt.target.style.border = "solid white 5px";

}

blackBoxes.addEventListener('click', boxChange);
```

Comment: `addEventListener` is available on elements, not on NodeList and `blackBoxes` is a NodeList not an element. So iterate over the NodeList and use `addEventListener` on each element inside it.

Comment: By the way, your loop is only going to make 144 boxes. Either start at 0 or go i<=145.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `blackBoxes` is a set of DOM elements, so you must iterate though that set and use `addEventListener` on each DOM element individually:

```
Array.from(blackBoxes).forEach(function(blackBox) {
    blackBox.addEventListener('click', boxChange);
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/od9md4y8/

`Array.from()` is required because even though `blackBoxes` is a "set" of DOM elements, it's not a true Array.  `Array.from()` will return a true Array made from the elements in `blackBoxes`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

However, there is a better way do this: add the event listener to the element when you create it!

```
if(i%5 === 0){
  repeatSq.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  repeatSq.style.border = "solid white 5px";
  repeatSq.className = "white";
}
else {
  repeatSq.addEventListener('click', boxChange);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/od9md4y8/1/

Comment: The second part is what I was looking for thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to adding a `click listener` to `every box`, you could also add one to your `wrapper` element:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        console.log(evt);
    });
});
```

Each `click event` comes with certain values you can use to determine which box has been clicked. In this case the `evt.target` gives you the element that has been clicked.

You can then determine what colors should be added and/or removed using your function.